# Paginação PHP com problemas

Tags: php, paginação

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou iniciando em manutenção do site de uma determinada pesquisa da minha universidade. Sou iniciante em PHP. O problema é que por exemplo: Quando no filtro seleciona "Sick", tem que vir todos os pacientes doentes, ele na primeira página faz isso, e deixa a opção "Sick" no filtro selecionado, além de colocar página "1" selecionado e página "2" como link para os outros registros. Quando clica no "2" ele sai do filtro e seleciona todos os registros, "Sick", "Healthy", etc...   Como fazer?
Abaixo todo o código da página index.php

```
<?php
    include("include/sesion.php");
    $total_paginas=0;
    $registros=$limite=30;
    $inicioM = 0; 
    $paginaM = 1;   
    $page=1;
    // pagina pedida 
    if (isset($_GET['pagina'])){ 
        $page = (int) $_GET["pagina"];  
        if ($page < 1){  
            $page = 1;  
        }  
    }else{ 
        $page = 1; 
    }
    $inicioM = ($page - 1) * $registros;
    $paginaM = $page;

    $MTtitulo="Prontuarios";
    $MTdescripcion="Prontuarios médicos.";
    include("include/top.php");
?>
<div class="span2">
<?php
    include("include/menu.php");
?>   
</div>
<div class="span10 bloco">
<?php
    $url="index.php?";
    $oprontuario=new CObjeto();
    $oprontuario->addLog($iduser, "Listado de pacientes");

    $prontuarios=array();
    $filtro=0;

    if(isset($_GET['filtro'])){
        $filtro=$_GET['filtro'];
        $url="index.php?filtro=".$filtro;
    }

    $order=1;
    $ordenarPor="id";
    if(isset($_GET['order'])){
        $order=$_GET['order'];
        switch ($order) {
            case 1: $ordenarPor="id";
            break;
            case 2: $ordenarPor="date_birth";
            break;
            case 3: $ordenarPor="name";
            break;
        }
        $url.="&order=".$order;
    }
    $by=1;
    if(isset($_GET['by'])){
        $by=$_GET['by'];
        if($by==2){
            $ordenarPor.=" desc";
            $url.="&by=".$by;
        }
    }
    $diag="";
    $diagnosis="";
    if(isset($_GET['diag'])){
        if($_GET['diag'] == 'X'){
            $escolhido = "X";
        }else {
            $diag=$_GET['diag'];
        }
        if(strlen($diag)>0){
            $diagnosis=" and visit.diagnosis='".$diag."'";
        }
    }
    $prontuarios=$oprontuario->listarProntuario($filtro, $diagnosis);
    $total=$oprontuario->getTotalProntuarios();
    $total_paginas = ceil($total / $registros); 
    $offset = ($page-1) * $limite; 
    $prontuarios=$oprontuario->listarProntuarioPag($offset,$limite,$filtro, $ordenarPor, $diagnosis);
    $i=0;
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5 form-inline"><strong>Show:</strong>
            <select id="filtro" class="span9">
                <option value="0" <?php if($filtro==0) echo "selected"?>>All patients</option> 
                <option value="1" <?php if($filtro==1) echo "selected"?>>Patients with mammography</option> 
                <!--  <option value="2" <php if($filtro==2) echo "selected"?>>Patients with ultrasound</option> 
                <option value="3" <php if($filtro==3) echo "selected"?>>Patients with magnetic resonancessonância magnética</option> 
                -->
                <option value="4" <?php if($filtro==4) echo "selected"?>>Patients without examination</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 form-inline"><strong>Sort by:</strong>
            <select id="order" class="span6">
                <option value="1" <?php if($order==1) echo "selected"?>>Registration date</option> 
                <option value="2" <?php if($order==2) echo "selected"?>>Age</option> 
                <option value="3" <?php if($order==3) echo "selected"?>>Name</option> 
            </select>
            <?php if($by==2){
            if (strpos($url,"&by=2")>=0) $url=str_replace("&by=2","",$url);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $url."&by=1"?>" title="Sort ascending" class="flechas"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
            <?php }else{
            if (strpos($url,"&by=1")>=0) $url=str_replace("&by=1","",$url);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $url."&by=2"?>" title="Sort downwards" class="flechas"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 pull-right form-inline">
            <?php
            if($_SESSION['id_user']==0){
            ?>
                <p align="right"><a href="addpr.php" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Adicionar Paciente</a></p>    
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span5 form-inline"><strong>Diagnostic:</strong>
            <select id="diagnosis" class="span8">
                <option value="" <?php if($diag=="") echo "selected"?>>All</option>
                <option value="S" <?php if($diag=="S") echo "selected"?>>Healthy</option>
                <option value="D" <?php if($diag=="D") echo "selected"?>>Sick</option>
                <option value="U" <?php if($diag=="U") echo "selected"?>>Unknown</option>
                <!--<option value="X" <?php if($diag=="") echo "selected"?>>Teste</option> -->
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <table width="100%" id="mytable" class="bordered" >
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Records</th>
            <th>Name</th>        
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Exams</th>
            <th>Diagnosis</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach($prontuarios as $prontuario)
        {
            if($i % 2 == 0)
                $class="spec";
            else
                $class="alt";
                $i++;
                $exames="";
            if($prontuario['termografia']>0)
                $exames.="Thermography";
            if($prontuario['mamografia']>0)
                $exames.=", mammography";

            $dianostico="Unknown";
            if($prontuario['diagnosis']=="S")
                $dianostico="Healthy";
            if($prontuario['diagnosis']=="D")
                $dianostico="Sick";
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><?php echo $prontuario['id']?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><?php if(strlen($prontuario['record']>0)) echo $prontuario['record']; else echo "Voluntária";?></td>
            <?php if($_SESSION['id_user']==0){?>  
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $prontuario['id']?>" title="Show record"><?php echo utf8_encode($prontuario['name']); ?></a></td>
            <?php } else{  ?>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $prontuario['id']?>" title="Show record">PRIVATE</a></td>
            <?php } ?>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><?php echo calcularedad(($prontuario['date_birth']))?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><?php echo $exames?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><?php echo $dianostico?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $class?>"><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $prontuario['id']?>" title="Show record"><i class="flaticon-zoom19"></i></a>&nbsp;
            <?php if($_SESSION['id_user']==0){ ?>
                <a href="modify.php?id=<?php echo $prontuario['id']?>" title="Editar Prontuario"><i class="flaticon-writing9"></i></a>&nbsp; 
                <a href="javascript:delpr(<?php echo $prontuario['id'] ?>)" title="Apagar Prontuario"><i class="flaticon-trash30"></i></a>&nbsp; 
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $url="index.php?filtro=".$filtro;
            $url.="&order=".$order;
            $url.="&by=".$by;
            if($total_paginas>1) {
                if(($paginaM - 1) > 0) {
                    echo "<li><a href='".$url."&pagina=".($paginaM-1)."'>Previous</a></li> ";
                }
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){ 
                    if ($paginaM == $i){
                        echo "<li><span class='activo'>".$paginaM."</span></li> ";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<li><a href='".$url."&pagina=".$i."'>$i</a></li> ";
                    }
                }
                if(($paginaM + 1)<=$total_paginas) {
                    echo "<li><a href='".$url."&pagina=".($paginaM+1)."'>Next</a><li>";
                }
            }
            ?> 
        </ul>
    </div><!--fin paginado-->
</div>
<script>
    $('.bordered tr').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
    function delpr(id)
    {
        var answer = confirm ("Tem certeza que deseja apagar o prontuario? \nTambém serão apagados as visitas do paciente");
        if (answer)
        window.location="delete.php?id="+id
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#filtro").change(function(){
            window.location="index.php?filtro="+this.value+"&order=<?php echo $order?>";
        });
        $("#order").change(function(){
            window.location="index.php?filtro=<?php echo $filtro?>&order="+this.value;
        });
        $("#diagnosis").change(function(){
            window.location="index.php?filtro=<?php echo $filtro?>&diag="+this.value;
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
    include("include/end.php");
?>
```

Comment: você precisa passar os parâmetros para pagina 2, estou analisando o código aqui para ajudar vc

Comment: manda como está o link da pagina 2 no navegador

Comment: `<a href='$url&pagina=".($paginaM+1)."'>`, você só passa a página, mas não passa o filtro atual.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss essa `$url` la no inicio tem o `$_GET` que pega o filtro, ou não?

Comment: @WeesSmith Mas parece que o filtro em questão é definido por `$_GET['diag']`, que não é adicionado à URL.